TOPtesi with Latin Modern fonts
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[tipotesi=custom]{toptesi}

%\setmainfont{TeXGyreTermes} % workaround: a font with bold sc glyphs

\begin{document}

\indici % culprit

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}

compiled with
latexmk --halt-on-error --file-line-error -lualatex ./foo.tex

Everything works! But this warning appears in the log:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 3.

It's strange because MWE doesn't contain a command to type small cap glyphs. Anyway, to suppress this warning I changed the font from Latin Modern to TeXGyreTermes. Surprise! Both fonts produces a PDF without small cap glyph. Is it an TOPtesi issue?
I found this piece of code in toptesi.dtx:
% It is also necessary to redefine the format of the unnumbered
% chapter entries in the table of contents so as to have page
% numbers in small caps.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak
      \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss\ifPDFTeX\normalfont\fi\scshape{#2}}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

I'm not an expert (== I don't know what this code does), but maybe it could be related with this unexpected behaviour.

The warning is simply telling you that Latin Modern Roman doesn't have small-caps (sc) bold (bx for Latin Modern), so LaTeX substitutes upright (n).
It is indeed generated by the code you excerpted, but could be equally generated by code in the document itself and is not a bug in the class:
% It is also necessary to redefine the format of the unnumbered
% chapter entries in the table of contents so as to have page
% numbers in small caps.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries

\bfseries switches to whichever font 'series' is setup for \bfdefault. For Latin Modern, this is bx, which is the bold extended series.
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak

#1 is typesetting the title of an unnumbered chapter. Notice that this is in bold, but not small-caps.
      \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss\ifPDFTeX\normalfont\fi\scshape{#2}}\par

This sets a box up of a set width to contain the page number on the right in the table of contents. This ensures you don't get ragged ends to the dotted lines. The dotted line for something which starts on page 0 should align with the end of the dotted line for something which starts on page 99. The way to ensure this is to put the page number in a box of set width, regardless of how wide the page number itself actually is.
\hss fills the rest of the space, preventing an under full box and pushing the page number to the right margin.
\ifPDFTeX\normalfont\fi\scshape{#2} is the crucial part. This tells LaTeX to switch to the default font, but only if compiling with pdfTeX. We're using LuaTeX, so \normalfont does nothing. \scshape{#2} switches to small-caps, so effectively we're in bold extended + small-caps, which doesn't exist in Latin Modern, so LaTeX substitutes bold extended upright.
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

But the scope of that \scshape{} is not the entire contents line. The switch to small-caps only applies to the page number. So, even when you switch to TG Termes, you don't 'see' bold small-caps. That's not because bold small-caps isn't used. It's because the numbers in bold small-caps don't look any different from the numbers in bold upright:

Here's the same sampler with just fontspec loaded, so we get Latin Modern:


Is there a way to print the font sample quickly without doing it manually?

@EmanueleNardi sorry, what do you mean exactly? I just compiled a document? I can add the source to my answer, but I thought it would just be a distraction as it really didn't seem relevant?

I was wondering if there’s a faster way to write out "0123456789 ABC abc Latin Modern Roman regular upright {\scshape 0123456789 ABC ABC LATIN MODERN ROMAN REGULAR SMALL-CAPS}" without typing it all manually.

@EmanueleNardi there is fonttable which provides e.g. \digitsext, \aztext and so on. you could use \f@family for the family. however, for this I just wrote one line 0123456789 ABC abc Latin Modern Roman regular upright and then copied it in VIM. 0123456789 ABC abc Latin Modern Roman regular small-caps, surrounded it by {} and added \textsc. then I copied both lines and adapted for bold. you don't want all caps or you won't see small-caps.

TL;DR
Ignore the warning and live peacefully :)
Code Analysis
This code snippet redefines the \l@chapter macro, which formats the chapter entries in the table of contents (TOC).
At line 9: \leavevmode \bfseries ensures that the following text is treated as regular text (\leavevmode) rather than as part of a math mode and sets the font to bold (\bfseries).
At line 12: #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak inserts the chapter title (#1), with \nobreak commands preventing page breaks before and after it. The \hfil command pushes the title to the left within the line.
At line 13: \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss\ifPDFTeX\normalfont\fi\scshape{#2}} creates a horizontal box (\hb@xt@) with a fixed width (\@pnumwidth) for the page number.

\hss: Pushes the page number to the right within the box;
\ifPDFTeX\normalfont\fi: Ensures the default font is used when compiling with pdflatex;
\scshape{#2}: Sets the page number in small caps.

I believe you now have all the necessary information to understand why the compiler is complaining about the lack of a font with bold small caps glyphs.
Compiler Warning Explanation
The compiler issues a warning about the lack of a font with bold small caps glyphs because the Latin Modern fonts (\usepackage{lmodern}) do not include bold small caps. Consequently, \scshape is ignored, and text with \bfseries\scshape is rendered in bold only, as no appropriate font is available.
Ignoring the Warning
This warning can usually be disregarded unless the distinction provided by small caps is essential for the reader's understanding.

Related Small Caps and Bold Face
